# awk variables and printf

Tags: awk, printf, gawk

I have a CSV file like this:

```
"Player","VPIP"
"$GIU$37","21.01"
"$VaSko$.017","14.11"
"*Lampiaao*","16.15"
"111bellbird","30.30"
"1221Vik1221","21.97"
"16266+626","20.83"
"17victor","16.09"
"1980locky","11.49"
"19dem","22.81"
"1lllllllllll","20.99"
......
```

and I would like to print lines like the following in (g)AWK, into an output file with extracting informations from between the quotes:

```
<note player="player ID comes here" label="a number between 0-7 based on the number belong to the player's VPIP value" update="this one is irrelevant, one nuber can be used for all the lines"></note>
```

So a printed line would look like this:

```
<note player="17victor" label="2" update="1435260533"></note>
```

Obviously, I'd like to ignore the first line of the CSV file when reading it because it contains only the header data. The label number criteria is:

0: VPIP > 37.5

1: VPIP < 10

2: VPIP between 10 - 16.5

7: The rest.

Any idea about how it can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Script

Try this [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
    update = 34513135
}
NR != 1 {
    vpip = $2 
    gsub(/"/, "", vpip)

    if (vpip > 37.5)
        label = 0
    else if (vpip < 10)
        label = 1
    else if (vpip < 16.5)
        label = 2
    else
        label = 7
    printf "<note player=%s label=%s update=%s></note>\n", $1, label, update
}
```

## Explanation

It's quite simple really:

1. First we set the field separator to a comma so the input file has two fields per line (i.e. a record).
2. We also set the update variable in the `BEGIN` block (this gets executed before parsing the file.
3. Then we execute the next code for every line that is not the first one `NR != 1`.
4. Here we set the second field as the `vpip` and remove the quotes to compare it to an integer.
5. Now we take the VPIP and map it to the correct label, we store this in `label`.
6. Finally print the line in the desired format.

## Usage

To use this code you should execute `awk -f script.awk file`. Where `script.awk` is the name of the script and `file` is the path to the input file.

Example usage:

```
$ cat file
"Player","VPIP"
"$GIU$37","21.01"
"$VaSko$.017","14.11"
"*Lampiaao*","16.15"
"111bellbird","30.30"
"1221Vik1221","21.97"
"16266+626","20.83"
"17victor","16.09"
"1980locky","11.49"
"19dem","22.81"
"1lllllllllll","20.99"
$ awk -f script.awk file 
<note player="$GIU$37" label=7 update=34513135></note>
<note player="$VaSko$.017" label=2 update=34513135></note>
<note player="*Lampiaao*" label=2 update=34513135></note>
<note player="111bellbird" label=7 update=34513135></note>
<note player="1221Vik1221" label=7 update=34513135></note>
<note player="16266+626" label=7 update=34513135></note>
<note player="17victor" label=2 update=34513135></note>
<note player="1980locky" label=2 update=34513135></note>
<note player="19dem" label=7 update=34513135></note>
<note player="1lllllllllll" label=7 update=34513135></note>
```

### Notes

If you have further questions, leave a comment and I will elaborate.

Comment: I needed to change if ($2 > 37.5) to if (vpip > 37.5) and do this with the rest of the code, now it's working like a charm, thank you very much for your help, this might be very very useful for me in the future :)

Comment: @sasieightynine Of course, good catch, shows you understand the code :) Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your questions and upvote if you deem it a quality answer. Also `man awk` could be helpful to you!